# Open my site in default browser from facebook insted of facebook browser

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, browser

My website works well on all modern desktop and mobile browsers. Some functionality will not work with facebook browser on smartphones. This is a problem because my site works badly when someone share the link on facebook. One functionality that does not work is upload files.

Example scenario on Android smartphone

1. The user clicks on a link to my page in the facebook app
2. My Website opens in facebook browsers
3. The user can not e.g upload any files
4. The user clicks on the three dots in the top right corner of the Facebook browser and choose to open in Google Chrome instead. Uploading files works well.

Is it possible to do anything so my website always opens in a "real" web browser from the facebook app (all users not just me)? Can I do anything else?

I use php, javascript (jQuery), html5 and css3 on my website.

Comment: same problem occur with me....the facebook browser does not support modern css framework.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't influence this behaviour. But why is the file upload not working? That should work just fine. Can you give more details about that (in a new question)?

Comment: facebook browser keeps reloading my webpage. While in chrome and firefox the webpage is opening normally